# Set affiliate cookie with jQuery via CSS classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to set affiliate cookies to links based on a CSS class.

Say for example I'm an affiliate for Ebay and an affiliate for Amazon and I had both links.

Ebay url class="ebay" and Amazon url class="amazon"

So the jQuery would be coded to set the affiliate cookie `onclick`, based on the class of the URL.

Is it possible?

EDIT: This is what I tried so far:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

$('a').click(function(e) {
  var affiliate = $(this).attr('afflink');

  <img src="afflink" />

  return false;
})
</script>
```

Comment: you may like to do other people a favour and mark your previous questions as answered, show respect to those people that took time to help you, before asking new ones ;-) just a friendly nudge

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
  var affiliate = $(this).attr('class');

  // do something with it

  return false;
})
```

Comment: Any ideas what to put in do something with it? As there will be thousands of url's it would need to just be something very simple. Can that load an image?

Comment: That can do whatever you want, as soon as you know what you want. Please update the question with more detailed information.

Comment: Oh I would like to load any cookie. Say Amazon homepage aff cookie for any link even if not the amazon homepage. Essentially to stuff the cookie?

Comment: you can't mess with cookies from another websites, that would be a big security breach.

Comment: No they are affiliate cookies. Yes I can't mess with them but I am allowed to set them in another person browser.

Comment: Not sure I'm following you there, perhaps you should update your question in more detail.